# User Admins too zealous in their closing of questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, moderation

Stack Overflow should be a place for both experts and those who are just getting into programming.

I am a self-taught programmer and I can attest for the fact that the most difficult thing about teaching yourself anything is knowing where to start and where to look.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148633/how-to-write-a-windows-application-closed) was closed on Stack Overflow as "not a real question" by a large number of user admins.

That's just wrong. The question looks and sounds genuine - an earnest beginner asking a community of programmers for some advice on where to start - and the question was closed.

I'm not sure if there's any way to combat this or if the community feels like this is even a problem, but I thought it should be brought up. It wasn't like this in the beginning when only a few users had admin rights.

Also, I should add: The fact that there are *reputation points* involved means that, to some extent (maybe a large extent?), Stack Overflow is an incentive based community. If I feel that responding to question is worth the points I could potentially get out of it, I will answer it. If I don't feel it's worth the effort, I won't answer.

This is how a free-market system works. I'm not sure how much we need moderators to close questions. We should let the community decide whether a question is worth answering, not a select few individuals.

On the number of rep points needed to have the ability to close a question, Colin Mackay [suggests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7120/user-admins-too-zelous-in-their-closing-of-questions/7139#7139) that "[m]aybe the bar has to be set a little higher[...]? ... Some people are more trigger happy than others. So as the 1227 people currently able to close questions grows so do the number of trigger happy ones."

Comment: I agree with you, some of the answers were pretty good as well.

Answer (score 11):

[From the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Programming questions, of course! As long as your question is:
>
> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere
>
> ... it is welcome here. No question is too trivial or too "newbie". Oh yes, and it should be about programming. You know, with a computer.

Does "How do I write a Windows application" sound "detailed and specific" to you? We want to help you, but you need to get yourself to a point that you can ask a more detailed question as to what you want to do. The answer to your question could literally be a whole book's length.

Comment: That's the title.
The question, I believe, is specific enough and if it isn't, *you* don't have to devote the time to answer it. You can just pass over it and let someone else give it a shot. Just because it isn't specific enough for you (and I use 'you' here in a general way), I don't think affords you the right to close the question. Just because you wouldn't answer it does not mean someone else won't.

Comment: @Tyler: the text you see in the question used to be the title. I edited the current title. It would have been closed instantly if I hadn't fixed the title.

Comment: @John Saunders

Yeah I saw that. That was 1) nice of you and 2) a highly appropriate use of an admin privilege

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good question. But it's hot here, really hot, and i'm tired. So i down-voted and voted to re-open: it's programming-related, after all...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to have to take objection with you...

> This question was closed on StackOverflow as "not a real question" by a large number of user admins.

The question was **not** closed by any admin/moderator; just regular users.

> I'm not sure how much we need moderators to close questions. We should let the community decide whether a question is worth answering, not a select few individuals.

Which is exactly what happened. No "select few individual" has had *any* involvement in that thread.

Maybe I'm missing your definition of "admin"... anybody with a rep over 3k can vote to close. At the time of writing that is the first 35 pages of users, plus another 2 = 1227 users. Not exactly what I call the "select few".

Comment: Maybe the bar has to be set a little higher then? As the community grows so will the numbers with sufficient Rep to perform these actions. Some people are more trigger happy than others. So as the 1227 people currently able to close questions grows so do the number of trigger happy ones. Now, maybe the question was right to be shut down, but I've felt some didn't deserve it. Or that the explanation given, as I've brought up elsewhere, was inappropriate.

Comment: They can *vote* to close it; it still takes 5 votes...

Comment: @Marc: I think his point being that as their numbers increase it'll become more and more common for 5 of them to hit the trigger on the same question too.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't just vote to close it; I did a bit of editing first - the original title had all of the question text in it.

Maybe we should change the text of "not a real question" to be "not an answerable question, too broad, or not specific enough". The *question* here was (paraphrased), "what should I do (tutorial to read) next to write a Windows application".

The only real answer to that question is, "It depends". What kind of Windows Application? How could we guide this person when he's given us no idea where he wants to go?

Comment: We could begin by guiding.  For starters, when I was beginning to learn to write Windows apps I didn't knew there where different kinds of apps.  How could he/she know what to ask?

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? I ssaid, "how could we guide this person when he's fiven us no idea where he want to go". BTW, how did you lear there were different kinds of program? And, was it important that you learned that in one day?

Comment: @John Saunders 
"was it important that you learned that in one day?"
Why do you feel it's important that information such as this be acquired slowly?

Comment: Nobody learns that fast. On the other hand, many people copy and paste that fast. There's a difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that in the case of that particular question it might have become detailed enough by adding a sentence suggesting a specific, simple problem to solve:

> For instance, if I wanted to make an
>   application with displaying a window
>   with the text "Hello world!", how
>   would I do that using C?

What happens here is that the question becomes a lot more specific; we create clear borders, which makes is *a lot* easier to provide useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I want to write a program that fundamentally changes human existance.

Where should I start?

Comment: For you to even make that comparison implies that you'll never understand why it makes no sense.

Comment: Hurf.     Durf.